# I have 2 same route in node.js but Swagger is showing only one

Tags: node.js, swagger

i have 2 same route positions

`Router.get("/positions",getAll),positionsRouter.put("/positions",updatePosition);`

and when i am adding tihs route in swagger it's only showing first one in this case get route and not put route what can i do except changing name of route ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf4Or.png)

Comment: You are calling the same endpoint with `/positions`. I don't have experience with Swagger, but I'd bet whichever route is defined last is accessed. You can't have 2 exact same endpoints do different things outside of defining one for `GET` and one for `POST`, how do you know what code to call to execute the view?

Comment: What library/framework do you use (e.g. `swagger-node-express` or something else)? Can you please post the full config code where the controllers are set up?

Comment: i am using node-express yes